# GoogleMaps SDK - Failed to load Info.plist

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm following the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) to manually install GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces SDKs (v3.0.3) and after dragging the frameworks, adding to the project target, and copying the bundle resources, the project successfully builds but fails to install on the simulator with the following error:

```
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path 
/Users/raphaeloliveira/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/
Devices/DF9C1649-ED71-47D9-9E36-28F53FF59B24/data/Library/Caches/
com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/
temp.xSOM90/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework
```

The downloaded zip files indeed don't include a plist on the framework folder which is odd. I noticed that the bundle resources for the GooglePlaces SDK does contain an Info.plist but that doesn't seem to suffice, even when dragger under `.framework/`. Has anyone experienced this and found a solution or workaround?

PS: cleaning, deleting derived data, restarting simulator and XCode workarounds don't work.

Comment: I had the same issue with MobileVLCKit, where I needed to have it in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" but not in "Embedded Binaries" (in an iOS project). Not sure if that can help.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with SpotifySDK. And I solved it as indicated in the comment. It has to be in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", but not in "Embedded Binaries". You both find them in "build phases".

Comment: For my case, `General` > `Frameworks, Libraies, and Embedded Content` make it from *Embed & Sign* to **Do Not Embed**. Seems that if you want to embed a framework, it must have `info.plist`.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I just enabled the "copy only when installing" checkbox in the "build phase" > "embed framework".

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: This worked for me. My box was unchecked and the destination was set to plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, it was as simple as to set the frameworks to "Do not embed"

[image]

Thx to: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126598